# NPM Install add custom warning message

Tags: node.js, npm, warnings, npm-install

How should I got about adding a warning message when a user tries to install a given version of a library?

For example, when you install `babel-preset-es2015` you get the following warning:

> Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!

By inspecting their code I saw they add a `deprecated` entry in their package.json as follows:

```
"deprecated": "  Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update! ",
```

I can easily add that, but I'm not actually deprecating anything. I just want to warn users that they are installing an alpha version and there may be changes in the API.

**Question**

Is there a similar entry to `deprecated` that can do the job?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's not necessarily a way you can do that, or not with given fields like `"deprecated"`

What you can do, which is a little bit of a workaround, is adding a post-install [script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts), that outputs a string to the console if you mark a version as alpha.

```
// package.json
{
  "version": "1.2.3-alpha.2",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node postinstall.js"
  }
}

// postinstall.js
const package = require('./package.json')

if (package.version.includes('alpha')) {
  console.log('You are using an alpha version. Beware!')
}
```

Comment: Looks like this has stopped working https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3647

Answer (score 3):

Please check out belows:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/deprecate
- https://docs.npmjs.com/deprecating-and-undeprecating-packages-or-package-versions

```
$ npm deprecate <pkg>[@<version>] <message>
```

Example:

```
$ npm deprecate some-lib@"< 1.0.0" " Thanks for using it. we recommend using new version, 1.x.x. Please check out https://example.com"
```

then,

```
$ yarn
yarn install v1.16.0
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning some-lib@0.1.5:  Thanks for using it. we recommend using new version, 1.x.x. Please check out https://example.com
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
✨  Done in 5.25s.
Time: 0h:00m:06s
```